# Last button clickable in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have multiple buttons in UITableViewCell. Only last button is clickable. I defined my button in `customCell.h` file

Following is my Code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomCell *cell;
    if (IS_IPAD) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VCustomCell_iPad"];
    }else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell_iPhone"];
    }

    NSDictionary *dicCustom = [self.arrCustom objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell configureVanStockDetail:dicCustom];

    [cell.btnOrder addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPurchaseOrderClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

Following code is from `customCell.h` file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btnOrder;
```

Code from `CustomCell.m` file

```
- (void) configureVanStockDetail:(NSDictionary *)objCustom {
   ...
   ...
    int count = 0
    for (NSDictionary *dicPO in arrPO) {
        self.btnOrder = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.btnOrder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.btnOrder.tag = count;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.btnOrder];
        count++;
    }
}
```

From above code, can anyone tell me why only lastly created button is clickable.

Comment: I created a new project and made a table view with a custom tableview cell and the button the selector gets added to all cells

https://github.com/CongL3/StackOverFlowQuestions

That leads me to believe its something outside of the code  are showing us

Comment: @CoNgL3 Thanks for your efforts. Here I am creating button programatically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a single button property and you are overriding the property for every new button you are adding.

You can create a button array in the cell and then loop through that array inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

e.g

`CustomCell.h`

add

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *btnArray;`

In the `CustomCell.m file` add

`[self.btnArray addObject:self.btnOrder];`

TableView Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...
    ...

    for (UIButton *button in cell.btnOrder) {
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPurchaseOrderClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
}
```

I think this should work.